# Configuration form confirmation

Tags: 8, forms

I have a configuration form which extends `ConfigFormBase`.

How can I add a confirmation popup/page to give a message to the user that some field has certain value and do you wish to continue form submission?

I know there also is the `ConfirmFormBase` class but I don't have a clue how to implement this in my configuration form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you could easily implement ConfirmFormBase with the config form. It might be easier to turn your form into a multistep form and have step 2 with a simple submit button/message for confirmation rather than trying to implement ConfirmFormBase

That should achieve essentially the same thing

Comment: OP already found `ConfirmFormBase` but they don't know how implement this in `ConfigFormBase`.

Comment: Ah sorry I misread the question. Maybe the best solution would be to turn the form into a multistep form and have step 2 with a simple confirmation submit button rather than trying to implement ConfirmFormBase